# ES6 module concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Developing a web project in **JavaScript ES6**, I currently use [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) to compile my modules from ES6 to ES5, thinking that in the future, when browser will support ES6, I would be able to skip that transpilation step.

In the end, because I don't want to download several js pieces at start up, I have a single file that contains all my modules converted into ES5, thanks to Traceur.

But to validate this choice, I was wondering if this could still be possible the day I would keep the source in ES6. If I simply concatenate them, there will be invalid imports and name conflicts.

It looks like it has not been designed for it and it would require a extra processing step to merge them correctly.

How are we suppose to handle ES6 single file project defined with several modules ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate ES6 modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27488485/1048572), see also [Concatenate imports in modules in babeljs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31015250/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

This will be solved by bundling, as described here: http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/es6-modules-browsers.html in chapter 3.
So this is possible and validate your approach, although I couldn't find an implementation of the corresponding compilation step on the web, but it should arise when people start using ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1):

In the near future, there won't be anymore the need to build single file project thanks to `HTTP/2`.

See: [Why bundle optimizations are no longer a concern in HTTP/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861591/why-bundle-optimizations-are-no-longer-a-concern-in-http-2)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably going to be to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle your transpiled code into one file. Then I'd use uglify or Google's Closure Compiler to minify the file, given there is a slight size overhead given all the imports/exports that have to be dealt with.

Also, if you're willing to use Babel instead of Traceur, there's a Babel plugin for browserify to make things really easy.