# How do I concatenate ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

How can I concatenate ES6 modules?

```
var foo = 2; // This would normally be scoped to the module.
export function Bar() {}

// ...concatenate...

import { Bar } from 'javascripts/bar' //This file no longer exists in the concatenated scenario.
export function Bam() {}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `//This file no longer exists in the concatenated scenario.`? You have to import it from a file, or include its content inline. Are you trying to import Bar without a separate file to define Bar in?

Comment: What do you mean by concat? What's wrong with creating a third file that exports both of the two modules' items?

Comment: @DaveS I mean that the file `javascripts/bar` no longer exists after concatenation (because it has been concatenated).

Comment: @Benjamin I see now that I can perform a transpilation step before concatenation, so this question is somewhat moot.

Comment: It is impossible in the current ES6 syntax to declare two modules in the same file. Does this answer your original question?

Comment: Wait, that last statement is wrong, `System.module` has just been removed from ES6 and put in a different specification - this gives me a headache :S

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ES7?

Comment: @Ben no they're putting it in a different "living standard" so that browsers and node can discuss it and work on it checking out what works and what doesn't in faster iterations.

Comment: @Ben, so is "es6 transpilation and then concatenation" the answer then? i.e. is there something else to consider?

Comment: @justin personally I can recommend babel (used to be 6to5) it will gladly do this for you in the build step - super useful and produces very nice code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum cool, ok thanks. I already use 6to5 (just found out it's been renamed...) through Grunt... then I use a separate task to do the concatenation. I haven't looked too much into it but I guess there ought to be a way to do it straight through "Babel" - thx

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2020-09-02:** Esperanto was replaced by [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org) some time ago, and is a great choice for this problem. Depending on your needs, [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) may also be a good choice.

---

If what you want to do is create a single JavaScript file that does not internally use ES6 modules, so that you can use it with browsers/node today, then I recommend using [Esperanto](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto) (full disclosure, I'm a maintainer of the project). It allows you to create a bundle that concatenates all of the files together *without* the use of a loader like you'd get using something like browserify or webpack. This typically results in smaller code (no loader), better dead code elimination (when using a minifier like Google Closure Compiler or UglifyJS), and better performance as the JS interpreter is better able to optimize the result.

Here's an example usage, but note that there are [plenty of tools to integrate Esperanto into your workflow](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=esperanto):

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var esperanto = require( 'esperanto' );

esperanto.bundle({
  base: 'src', // optional, defaults to current dir
  entry: 'mean.js' // the '.js' is optional
}).then( function ( bundle ) {
  var cjs = bundle.toCjs();
  fs.writeFile( 'dist/mean.js', cjs.code );
});
```

This example is taken from the [wiki page on bundling ES6 modules](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto/wiki/Bundling-multiple-ES6-modules).

Comment: link esperantojs.org goes to some porn/spam site

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take a look at http://webpack.github.io and then combine it with babel.

alternatively you can do it with babel alone:

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: Can you describe how to achieve it with babel cli alone ?

Comment: Looks like babel has the ability to concatenate files, but it won't inline import/require.  Those import/require calls will still be present in the concatenated file.  Looks like you really need to use something like Webpack to get it to resolve all those script dependencies.