# Concatenate imports in modules in babeljs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am new to all ES6 transpiling and I was planning on using BabelJS.

Is there a way to concatenate scripts with there imports in `babelJS`

I have the following

home.js imports home/home-navbar and home/home-slider

I want the output to contain both home/home-navbar and home/home-slider but put them all in one file home.js

Can I do this in BabelJS? and if not what would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate ES6 modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27488485/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do this in BabelJS?

No, [not yet](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1681).

> what would the proper way to do it?

Not sure about the proper way, but there are alternatives. Tools like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [esperanto](http://esperantojs.org/) compute module dependencies and bundle them into a single files (or multiple if desired).

Depending on your specific use case you could also write a simple script that concatenates all files.

Comment: @Bergi: I couldn't get to work with my project yet, but it does look good!

Comment: I think I'll give esperanto a try, thanks for the tip

Comment: From [https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto](https://github.com/esperantojs/esperanto): This project is no longer under active development. To bundle ES6 modules, use Rollup. To convert ES6 modules to another format, use Babel.

Answer (score 0):

Babel runs in the client, and it doesn't actually alter system files, which you would need a server for.

> If you want to share resources, you can always transport objects via the shared `window` object

```
class MyClass {
    constructor (config) {
        super(config);
        this.config = config;
    }
}

window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

---

```
var MyClass = window.MyClass;

class ExtendedClass extends MyClass {
    constructor (config) {
        super(config);
        console.log(this.config); // from MyClass
    }
}
```