# what is the intention of extract all css in a single file

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

First, I don't understand what is the meaning for extract all css in a single file,
and What's the profit of doing that?
Moreover, I try use splitChunks of webpack4 to extract css but it is produced a js files. I think, it is not supposed to be produces a css files?
this is my code.

```
splitChunks: {
  cacheGroups:{
    vendors: {
      test: /\.js$/g,
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'vendors',
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 1
    },
    styles: {
      test: /\.less$/g,
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'styles',
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 1,
      enforce: true
    }
  }
}
```

ending this code produced a 'vendors.js' and 'styles.js', How come this?
thanks for your help;

Answer (score 1):

When you have different css files, the browser needs to make multiple requests to get all files. And every request took a lot of time, but imagine browser makes just one request.

And also when you bundled all css to a single file , usually u omit the redundant spaces in css file and basically you make the file pretty small.

[Please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861591/why-bundle-optimizations-are-no-longer-a-concern-in-http-2)

Comment: But why did the webpack generted js file after the packing ,not a css files?

Comment: webpack is responsible for both css and js bundle and minification. you should config it .

Comment: Can i config splitChunks to generate a css file? How configuration that?

Answer (score 1):

It's good to package multiple small css file together, it can reduce the request amount...
However, it seems terrible to use `splitChunks`>`cacheGroups`>`styles` when you are using `antd`, it looks like the `splitChunk` broke the dynamic import of the antd css, and when you open your page, it loads all `antd` css even you don't use in the current page

Answer (score 0):

this is my webpack config for one of my projects, with this config, you should be able to generate css and js files.

And it should be enough for any project.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'babel-regenerator-runtime',
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                WEBPACK: true
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'index.css',
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    }]
                })
            },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000' },
            {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'
            },
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Think you very much, but it is not config of webpack4. let me think about.

Comment: your right. so I should change my webpack version, let me get back to u after change it to version 4.