# Load all json files in a dir in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a dir that has a lot of json files. Is there a way that I could load all of them in to ReactJS? Ideally, that would be a dict with filenames as keys and the json as values.

Example: if there are three json files (`a.json`, `b.json`, and `c.json`) under `static/json/` directory, what I wanted to do is to have a dict that has the following structure:

```
{
    'a':<parsed json from a.json>, 
    'b':<parsed json from b.json>, 
    'c':<parsed json from c.json>
}
```

That is essentially equivalent to do sth like `import a from './static/json/a.json'` 3 times and merge to a large json.

Comment: you can use webpack to bundle all file to a single  js

Comment: in here I shared a webpack config file from one of my react based project.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833162/4287032

Comment: @Arash Sorry for this one I could not use webpack.

Comment: @jsDevia Due to some reasons I could not use webpack. Any other sols?

Comment: you could also use grunt or gulp.

Comment: @jsDevia Could you provide a minimum example here? I checked both and it seems they are both for large scale projects (but here I just want to load those files in - it is like a `os.listdir` and then read json iteratively.

Comment: Both grunt and gulp can be used for every project, small scale or large scale.I had used them in both kind of projects.

Comment: @jsDevia What I am targeting to is sort like solving the problem without introducing new packages. Do you know whether read jsons in a dir is doable in pure ReactJS/Javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I don's know exactly what it is you want, can u provide more detail about question.

Comment: @jsDevia Updated. Does it make more sense?

Comment: 1-these json files, are they in development stage or production ? 
2-what is the content of these json files ?

Comment: @jsDevia 1. currently in dev but later need to be in prod. However, low performance is acceptable if needed to maintain the current structure (a dir has a few json files). 2. They are all formatted small json files, nothing special.

Comment: I wrote a solution for your problem, but my solution is in webpack environment, what is your environment now for bundling ? you must have to have one now.
If u tell me i can convert my solution to yours.

Comment: @jsDevia Thanks! I was using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) for my project. I ran it with `npm start`/`npm build`.