# What is the reason behind having data URI instead of path for images less than 10kb in React?

Tags: reactjs, image, uri

In the Create React App documentation inside the [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) section, they say :

> importing images that
> are less than 10,000 bytes returns a data URI instead of a path. This
> applies to the following file extensions: bmp, gif, jpg, jpeg, and
> png.

The reason for them is :

> To reduce the number of requests to the server

But is it specific to how React works (updating the DOM for example) or it's a wide spread practice in web development in order to reduce load times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a practice that's particular to React. Whether something gets rendered via React or by ordinary HTML, if an image is rendered using a data URI, if the data URI exists in the code already (either bundled inside the JS or hard-coded into the HTML), no additional requests to the server will have to be made.

In contrast, if you have something like `src="theImage.png"`, that'll result in a request to the server to download the image.

> it's a wide spread practice in web development in order to reduce load times?

Yes.

If, for example, the web server was using HTTP 1.1, and you had, say, 25 images with `src`s pointing to different files, the sheer number of separate requests could present a problem - regardless of whether React was being used or not.

(HTTP/2 mitigates this problem at least somewhat - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30864259))